# Access UIAlertView's ViewController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uialertview

```
var message = new UIAlertView();
message.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.SecureTextInput;
message.Title = "Enter Your Password";
message.AddButton("Login");
message.CancelButtonIndex = 0;
message.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(139, 67, 103);
message.Show();
message.Clicked += Message_Clicked;
```

Hello. This is my code for creating a `UIAlertView` that has a button and a textbox in it. I'm trying to access it's Controller so that I can manipulate it's subviews. How can I do it?

Comment: Hi, what do you want to do with subviews of UIAlertView's ViewController ? You can detail show info about your want effect.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to change the color of it’s different sections, so as an example I can’t say, message.BackgroundColor = ...;

Comment: Okey , got it ! I have updated in answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/alerts) :

> Starting with iOS 8, UIAlertController has completed replaced UIActionSheet and UIAlertView both of which are now deprecated.
>
> Unlike the classes it replaced, which are subclasses of UIView, UIAlertController is a subclass of UIViewController.

The simplest alert added TextField, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

The code to display a simple alert is as follows:

```
var alertController = UIAlertController.Create("Title", "Pleasr input your name", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

//Add Text
alertController.AddTextField(texfield => { texfield.Placeholder = "Please Input "; });

//Add Action
alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, alert => {
    UITextField envirnmentNameTextField = alertController.TextFields[0];
    Console.WriteLine("Your input is :" + envirnmentNameTextField.Text);
}));

// Present Alert
PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);
```

If want to change color of message or Title , you can use `NSMutableAttributedString` to realize it.

```
//set color to meesage NSForegroundColorAttributeName

UIStringAttributes attrTextColor = new UIStringAttributes();
attrTextColor.ForegroundColor = UIColor.Purple;

NSMutableAttributedString messageText = new NSMutableAttributedString("Please input your name");
messageText.AddAttributes(attrTextColor, new NSRange(0, 6));
alertController.SetValueForKey(messageText, new NSString("attributedMessage"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This API is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller?language=objc). You should use `UIAlertController`.

Comment: Hi Ivan. Thanks for your answer. I actually wanted to use YIAlertController, but I’m unfortunately stuck at some point. I’m not sure how I can add a TextField as it gets an Action<UITextField> as an input. Can you please guide me on that too?